# Rubyでcreated_atのようなdatetime型自作カラムに時刻を値として入れたいです

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**やりたいこと**
自作アプリ内に追加したcreated_atのようなdatetime型のカラムに値を入れたいのですが、うまいこと行きません。

**現状**
deviseを用いたユーザー登録の仕様で、いくつか追加したカラムがあります。その中で、”received_at”というカラムがあるのですが、その第1段階で、ユーザー作成の際にその時点での時間を入れたいのですがうまくいきません。下にコードを書くのでどこがいけないのか教えていただきたいです。

**Users_controller.rb**

```
class UserController < xxx
  before_action :authentificate_user!
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.received_at = Time.now
    if @user.save
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Please check your email to activate your account."
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

大雑把に言うとこういう書き方をしているのですが、この `@user.received_at = Time.now` の箇所でイメージとしては、created_atのようにその時点での時刻を入れたいのですが、コマンドプロンプトで確認すると、ユーザー作成なんかは出来ているのですが、`received_at = nil` になってしまいます。

何か良いアドバイスが有れば、よろしくお願いします。

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string "unconfirmed_email"
    t.integer "failed_attempts", default: 0, null: false
    t.string "unlock_token"
    t.datetime "locked_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "name"
    t.date "birthday"
    t.datetime "received_at"
    t.index ["confirmation_token"], name: "index_users_on_confirmation_token", unique: true
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
    t.index ["unlock_token"], name: "index_users_on_unlock_token", unique: true
end
```

deviseの基本的なものがほとんどですが、いくつかカラムを追加しています。

追記２

**ユーザー登録時のコマンドプロンプト**

この最後の `received=at =nil` が気になってます。

```
Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2022-05-23 20:55:00 +0900
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"name"=>"ささ", "birthday"=>"2022-05-03", "email"=>"xxxxxxx", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"アカウント登録"}
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists? (0.7ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "xxxxxxx"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Create (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "reset_password_token", "reset_password_sent_at", "remember_created_at", "sign_in_count", "current_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "last_sign_in_ip", "confirmation_token", "confirmed_at", "confirmation_sent_at", "unconfirmed_email", "failed_attempts", "unlock_token", "locked_at", "created_at", "updated_at", "name", "birthday", "received_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22) RETURNING "id"  [["email", "xxxxxxx"], ["encrypted_password", "[FILTERED]"], ["reset_password_token", "[FILTERED]"], ["reset_password_sent_at", "[FILTERED]"], ["remember_created_at", nil], ["sign_in_count", 0], ["current_sign_in_at", nil], ["last_sign_in_at", nil], ["current_sign_in_ip", nil], ["last_sign_in_ip", nil], ["confirmation_token", "[FILTERED]"], ["confirmed_at", nil], ["confirmation_sent_at", "2022-05-23 20:55:00.331651"], ["unconfirmed_email", nil], ["failed_attempts", 0], ["unlock_token", "[FILTERED]"], ["locked_at", nil], ["created_at", "2022-05-23 20:55:00.331554"], ["updated_at", "2022-05-23 20:55:00.331554"], ["name", "ささ"], ["birthday", "2022-05-03"], ["received_at", nil]]
```

Comment: 確認なのですが、`@user.received_at = Time.now` から `if @user.save` の間では `@user` には一切触れていないのでしょうか。触れていないのであれば、実は変更が保存されていなかったとか、変更がアプリに反映されていなかったとか、そういう類の原因な可能性はないか、など考えています。

Comment: createの部分を書き直しました．一応，これでまるまるコピーしてきました．特に触れていないので，どこかで記述ミスやらがあるのかもしれませんね．．．